# I have completed camera streams sharing through webrtc in Android App but now i need to share the screen with the remote peer

Tags: android, webrtc, screen-capture

I have been able to develop camera streaming App using WEBRTC. Two peers are connected. One is android App and another is Browser.I did this with Help of this guide. https://vivekc.xyz/getting-started-with-webrtc-for-android-daab1e268ff4(Sharing this in case anybody wants good documentation of web rtc). Now i want to share screen instead of camera streams.

I tried doing this using Media Projection API's. But after using this API the whole screen turns black and also the sdp going through is incorrect.
Can anyone help me with This. I tried doing this by.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.webrtc_layout);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
    sDeviceWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    sDeviceHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

    try{
        context = this;

        SignallingClient.getInstance().setChannelId("GINGER_1594035215_551_6336_THINK_1");

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, ALL_PERMISSIONS_CODE);
        }
        else if  (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            startScreenCapture();
        }
        else {
            // all permissions already granted
            start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

@TargetApi(21)
private void startScreenCapture() {
    MediaProjectionManager mediaProjectionManager =
            (MediaProjectionManager) getApplication().getSystemService(
                    Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
    startActivityForResult(
            mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), CAPTURE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@TargetApi(21)
private VideoCapturer createScreenCapturer() {
    if (mMediaProjectionPermissionResultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        showToast("User didn't give permission to capture the screen.");
        return null;
    }
    return new ScreenCapturerAndroid(
            mMediaProjectionPermissionResultData, new MediaProjection.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            showToast("User revoked permission to capture the screen.");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode != CAPTURE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
        return;
    mMediaProjectionPermissionResultCode = resultCode;
    mMediaProjectionPermissionResultData = data;
    start();
}
```

Then i added the screencaptureandroid to video capturer where earlier camera streams were added. But it is of no help.

```
    //Now create a VideoCapturer instance.
        VideoCapturer videoCapturerAndroid;
        videoCapturerAndroid=createScreenCapturer();
        //videoCapturerAndroid = createCameraCapturer(new Camera1Enumerator(false));
```

Can anyone help me with This.?

Comment: hi, were you able to make this work?

Comment: Yes. I will post answer in a day or two.

Comment: Any update, can you please share the code.

Comment: Please check.I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to answer the question by myself.I am sharing the code. Hopefully it will be helpful for anyone else working on the same project.

```
  Add this code in Oncreate
  
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.webrtc_layout);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
    sDeviceWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    sDeviceHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Then create screen capturer using this and call it in the beginning after permission check.

```
 @TargetApi(21)
private void startScreenCapture() {
    MediaProjectionManager mediaProjectionManager =
            (MediaProjectionManager) getApplication().getSystemService(
                    Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
    startActivityForResult(
            mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), CAPTURE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@TargetApi(21)
private VideoCapturer createScreenCapturer() {
    if (mMediaProjectionPermissionResultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        showToast("User didn't give permission to capture the screen.");
        return null;
    }
    return new ScreenCapturerAndroid(
            mMediaProjectionPermissionResultData, new MediaProjection.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            showToast("User revoked permission to capture the screen.");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode != CAPTURE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
        return;
    mMediaProjectionPermissionResultCode = resultCode;
    mMediaProjectionPermissionResultData = data;
    start();
}
```

Add screencepturer return to Video Capturer

```
  videoCapturerAndroid=createScreenCapturer();
        //videoCapturerAndroid = createCameraCapturer(new Camera1Enumerator(false));

        //Create MediaConstraints - Will be useful for specifying video and audio constraints.
        audioConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
        videoConstraints = new MediaConstraints();



        //Create a VideoSource instance
        if (videoCapturerAndroid != null) {
            surfaceTextureHelper = SurfaceTextureHelper.create("CaptureThread", rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());
            videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(videoCapturerAndroid.isScreencast());
            videoCapturerAndroid.initialize(surfaceTextureHelper, this, videoSource.getCapturerObserver());
        }
```

You are good to go now.It will work perfectly upto Android 9. Don't Stress if you want to use it in android 10. Just add this in a foreground service and show a notification always when screen mirroring is on and it will work perfectly.

Comment: can you share the code for camera feed capture if possible.

Comment: Can you please share the code of how you switch between camera and screen share? That would be really helpful. Thanks!